# Filtering Excel Data Instances

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Having trouble filtering data within a table (see below) where I want to distinguish the Unique ID column and study analytics on the first instances of IDs vs the second instances of the same IDs using COUNTIFS to sort using the remaining columns. If the unique ID shows up for the first time, it's labeled an input, and if it's the second time, it's an output. But I don't want to create a separate column because that would interfere with other formulae, so I can't figure out how to sort the first column.

For example, I would want all instances of inputs that were completed by John during Q1 of 2020 with completion = 100% and Deadline Met = Yes.

I have tried using

`=UNIQUE(FILTER([TableData], (E:E = "Yes") * (D:D = 100%) * (C:C > 12/31/2019) * (B:B = "John"))`

and also

`=COUNTIFS(B:B, "John", C:C, '>'&DATE(12/31/2019), D:D, >75%, E:E, "Yes")`

| Unique ID | Names | Date | Completion % | Deadline Met |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | John | 1/1/2020 | 100% | Yes |
| A1 | John | 1/3/2020 | 100% | No |
| B2 | Jack | 1/2/2020 | 100% | Yes |
| B2 | Jack | 1/6/2020 | 20% | No |
| C3 | John | 1/7/2020 | 50% | No |
| C3 | John | 1/9/2020 | 0% | Yes |

I'm not sure if I could filter with a dynamic array (`=filter(index(x,y,z))`)?

Comment: Try `=FILTER($A$2:$E$7,((ROUNDUP(MONTH($C$2:$C$7)/3,0)=1)*($D$2:$D$7=1)*($E$2:$E$7="Yes")*($B$2:$B$7="John")))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I've managed to filter out columns B:E without much issue, but once I've gotten there, I can't identify if the Unique ID in Column A is an input or output (first instance of the ID vs second instance) since both instances will have the same Unique ID (kind of defeating the purpose of it being an ID)

Comment: Try using this and let me know `=FILTER(FILTER($A$2:$E$7,((ROUNDUP(MONTH($C$2:$C$7)/3,0)=1)*($D$2:$D$7=1)*($E$2:$E$7="Yes")*($B$2:$B$7="John"))),{1;0})`

Comment: Or may be this one, `=INDEX(FILTER($A$2:$E$7,((ROUNDUP(MONTH($C$2:$C$7)/3,0)=1)*($D$2:$D$7=1)*($E$2:$E$7="Yes")*($B$2:$B$7="John"))),1,0)`